# Bootstrap: a button inside a jumbotron with a responsive image

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a full width jumbotron with a responsive image inside (The image itself scales with the screen size).

```
<div class = 'jumbotron'>
   <button type= 'button' id="read" class='btn btn-primary'>Button</button> 
</div>

.jumbotron {
    background: url('img/Banner-logo5.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 52.18%;
    /* (img-height / img-width * width) */
    /* (1067 / 2045 * 100) */
}
```

Obviously this approach pushes the content inside it outside the jumbotron. Is there any way to get content inside it, without breaking the current code / with the image inside the jumbotron still being responsive?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the issue?

Comment: remove css properties that you've added manually to jumbotron and see if that works

Comment: maybe so - http://jsfiddle.net/byLjyug1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ze4Lq1tu/

Comment: @Manoj Kumar I added a screenshot of the button being pushed outside.

Comment: @Dmitriy The second suggestion is pretty close but I would like to move the button more to the middle. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/f9tp1et7/

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


div{
    width: 100%;
}
div figure{
    padding-top: 36.56%;  /* 702px/1920px = 0.3656 */
    display: block;
    background: url("https://st.fl.ru/images/landing/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;  
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}


button{
    padding: 15px 50px;
    border: 0;
    background: #f00;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
button:hover{
    background: #c00;
}
```

```html
<div>    
    <figure>
        <button type='button'>Button</button> 
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much. I'm pretty new to the responsive design so this was driving me nuts.

Comment: @Paddelui I am very glad I could help